# INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' while using BCP

Tags: sql-server

I've looked at a number of related questions and answers, and I think I'm on the right path...but I cannot figure out something that will work. Things are made marginally more difficult because I running the BCP Utility from PowerShell introducing some additional quotes that might be causing me issues. The BCP Imports work well, except for one or two tables that must have indexes or computed columns. Anyway, here is one such table with the BCP command and output/error.

```
PS> $bcpImport = "bcp [$($data[33].schema_name)].[$($data[33].name)] in C:\tmp\[$($data[33].schema_name)].[$($data[33].name)].bcp -f C:\tmp\[$($data[33].schema_name)].[$($data[33].name)].xml -E -d $Database -S $LittleServer -T"

PS> $bcpImport
bcp [reference].[Provider] in C:\tmp\[reference].[Provider].bcp -f C:\tmp\[reference].[Provider].xml -E -d Test -S localhost\SQLEXPR2014 -T

PS> Invoke-Expression $bcpImport

Starting copy...
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 1000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 2000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 3000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 4000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 5000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 6000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 7000
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 1934
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]INSERT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

BCP copy in failed
```

So - let's just add the `-q` parameter/option; no dice - but different error.

```
PS> $bcpImport = "bcp [$($data[33].schema_name)].[$($data[33].name)] in C:\tmp\[$($data[33].schema_name)].[$($data[33].name)].bcp -f C:\tmp\[$($data[33].schema_name)].[$($data[33].name)].xml -E -d $Database -S $LittleServer -T -q"

PS> Invoke-Expression $bcpImport
SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name '[reference].[Provider]'.
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 11529
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an error; see previous errors for some of these.
```

`reference.Provider` does happen to be the correct table, so now I'm iterating through trying to add double quotes into the `$bcpImport` variable, or finding a way to scrap it entirely and run the code differently. It seems like `SQLCMD` has an option, `-I`, which works similar to how `-q` works, but I'm not using SQLCMD and BCP doesn't like `-I`...Is there something simple I'm missing here?

*Edit - adding a line to show the 'resolved' name without variables prior to `Invoke-Expression`

Comment: What is the actual constructed value of `$bcpImport`? Does the table actually exist in said database?

Comment: @Charlieface - I can grab the resolved version later, but it does exist. However...it seems that if you're using the `-q` option, then your table name can't have brackets (unless...it actually has brackets). It seems that `-q` is expecting me to use the name as is, so adding the brackets like I did suddenly becomes superfluous once you surround it with double quotes.

Comment: [Documentation says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#q) if you use the `-q` option then: `Enclose the entire three-part table or view name in quotation marks ("")`

Comment: Yes, the [Remarks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#specifying-identifiers-that-contain-spaces-or-quotation-marks) also say: `For owner, table, or view names that contain embedded spaces or quotation marks, you can either: 1) Specify the -q option, or 2) Enclose the owner, table, or view name in brackets ([]) inside the quotation marks.` However, I can't get anything with brackets inside the quotation marks to work - so it seems that the name within double quotes needs to be verbatim and without brackets. Either brackets without `-q` or no brackets

Comment: Correct, that is exactly what it says in option 1, these are mutually exclusive